# having trouble printing a triangle using java

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm currently doing the "learn to program in java" course on edex.org.
The problem I'm stuck on is the following:

Write for loops to produce the following output in the shape of a triangle:

1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777

this is my code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=7;i++){

for(int j=1; j<=i;j++){

    if(i==j){
        System.out.print(i);
    }else{

    System.out.println();
   } 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

}

Comment: Why the if block?

Comment: My thinking was that I needed a way to go the next line.

Comment: You need to walk through your code mentally as if you're the JVM and ask yourself as it "runs" what it's doing.